# How can I run Selenium WebDriver tests in an embedded QT Webkit browser?

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, qtwebkit

I am working on a series of web applications written using Google Web Toolkit (GWT). As part of our testing we have successfully used selenium-rc for a long time. We are looking to migrate to Selenium 2 and use the WebDriver interface.

The complication is that one of our clients is a custom .Net application which launches our web applications using an embedded QT Webkit browser. We are concerned that moving to Selenium 2 will mean that we are unable to run Selenium tests in this client which will be a big problem as it currently comprises the majority of our clients.

Having done some research all I have been able to find is the [webkitdriver](http://code.google.com/p/webkitdriver/) project on Google code. However this just seems to support testing against a headless webkit which isn't what we want.

Does anyone else have any experience of testing an embedded QT webkit browser using Selenium 2 and WebDriver? I would love to be able to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know, that it's an old question, but if you are still interested in it, you can use Qt WebDriver that was opensourced not too long ago. You can learn more about it here https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver/wiki . And by the way, you can test Qt applications too

Comment: Thanks for this. I love it when people update old questions with useful information.

Answer (score 1):

It will be a lot of work. For [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org), we integrate [Ghost Driver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver) which is an implementation of [WebDriver Wire](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol) protocol (see the [release notes](http://phantomjs.org/release-1.8.html) for version 1.8). You can see from the source code of Ghost Driver that it is far from trivial. On top of that, you need to hook the protocol implementation to various QtWebKit API, also quite an amount of work.

Comment: I feared as much. However that project is dead now so I'm not as bothered as I was :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [WWW::WebKit](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::WebKit), it is a drop-in replacement for WWW::Selenium using Gtk3::WebKit as browser instead of relying on an external Java server and an installed browser.